# Python Unicode, have unicode number in normal string, want to print unicode

Tags: python, unicode

Im using IDLE on windows 7. When I run the following code

```
uni = u"\u4E0D"
binary = uni.encode("utf-8")
print binary
```

It prints the unicode character with number 4E0D correctly. But here I have to hardcode the unicode number manually. Lets say I have a normal string format variable:

```
s="4E0D"
```

How do I convert this to the unicode character? Ie I want to do something like the following pseudocode

```
s="4E0D"
uni=u"\u"+s
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you manually encoding something to send to a binary stream, instead of simply setting the stream encoding once and for all? Manually.encode("utf-8") calling.encode("utf-8") the.encode("utf-8") encode.encode("utf-8") method.encode("utf-8") every.encode("utf-8") time.encode("utf-8")
 is.encode("utf-8") unclear.encode("utf-8") and.encode("utf-8") prone.encode("utf-8") to.encode("utf-8") error.encode("utf-8").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
s = '4e0d'
c = unichr(int(s, 16))
```

Comment: Hm but what if I want to have more letters in my string? for example I want to write
    u"a\u4E0D"
the total string is no longer an integer, is there any unichar equivalent for strings?

Comment: @JonathanLindgren: `u'a' + c`. `unichr` always takes one codepoint and returns a single character.

Comment: sorry maybe I wasnt clear, I want to be able to print the same as what is printed by u"a\u4E0D", but I want to have the string saved in a string variable. Ie I have:

    s="a\u4E0D"
and want to print s where \u4E0D is transformed to its unicode character

Comment: @JonathanLindgren: You need to parse it and run `unichr` on every Unicode escape separately.

Comment: @JonathanLindgren: Or prepend `u` prefix to it, and use `ast.literal_eval`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the quickest way, but readable at least:

```
s = "4E0D"
orig = "\u" + s
uni = orig.decode('cp1252')
```

Comment: This will not work, literal escapes are a syntax feature, you can't construct them on the go, at least not without resorting to `eval`. Also, decoding from `cp1252` will not do anything interesting.