# Unicode character that doesnt work alone, Python

Tags: python, unicode

Ok so I have another Python Unicode problem. In IDLE windows 7,The following code:

```
uni = u"\u4E0D\u65E0"
binary = uni.encode("utf-8")
print binary
```

prints two chinese characters, 不无, the correct ones. However, if I replace the first line with

```
uni = u"\u65E0"
```

ie only the second character, it prints æ— instead. Altough if I replace it with only the first character

```
u"\u4E0D"
```

it gives the correct output 不

Is this a bug, or what am I doing wrong?

COMPLETE CODE:

```
uni = u"\u4E0D\u65E0"

binary = uni.encode("utf-8")

print binary

uni = u"\u65E0"

binary = uni.encode("utf-8")

print binary

uni = u"\u4E0D"

binary = uni.encode("utf-8")

print binary
```

OUTPUT:

不无

æ—

不

Comment: Why are you ever calling `.encode` when you’re just printing to a stream?  This is your problem — AGAIN — in that you do not know what the stream encoding is.  Leave the Unicode strings as Unicode strings and set the stream encoding. Do not call `.encode` yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Unicode, have unicode number in normal string, want to print unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021331/python-unicode-have-unicode-number-in-normal-string-want-to-print-unicode)

Comment: Sorry I missed your answer on my other question (altough the questions are completely different). But How do I set the stream encoding once and for all then? I barely know what that means.

Comment: You’re right: python makes it stupidly difficult. One way is to specify `encoding='utf-8'` when you call `codecs.open`. Another is to set your `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to `utf-8`, which is what I do. In Python3 you can `import io;
 import sys;
 for s in ("stdin","stdout","stderr"):
     setattr(sys, s, io.TextIOWrapper(getattr(sys, s).detach(), encoding="utf8"))`. In Python2 you probably have to do something like `sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout)`.

Comment: @tchrist: Since IDLE uses the locale encoding (e.g. cp1252) and also uses proxies for stdio (pythonw.exe has no stdin, stdout, or stderr), setting PYTHONIOENCODING has no effect. If TCL/Tk returns Unicode (e.g. for `raw_input`), then maybe it wouldn't take too much coding to work around it. It prints Unicode with no problem (no need to encode it). But I suggest simply switching to another GUI shell. I like IEP for its simplicity; it has tabs, ties into toolkit event loops, supports any interpreter (Python 3, PyPy), uses LF instead of CRLF line endings, and its stdin/stdout channels are UTF-8.

Comment: @eryksun: That’s all good to know, and IEP sounds a lot cleaner. I use putty, bash, and vim, which seems good enough. I don’t know why Python makes dealing with encoded streams so difficult. Yes, it’s better than C — what isn’t? — but not as easy as Java or Perl. I believe some things will be better in 3.3, but don’t have the list handy. Me, I try to push for an all–UTF‑8 toolchain and stear clear of legacy locale encodings: those always make for a serious migraine in my experience.

Comment: @tchrist: Python isn't a new language. Its roots predate the web, when code pages were the norm. Python 3.3 will fix the narrow build problem (no more UTF-16 surrogate pairs) and the wide build problem (UTF-32 memory usage) by using a hybrid Latin-1, UCS-2 (BMP), and UCS-4 system. But it will probably hurt overall performance. Also the Windows console support may be mostly fixed in 3.3.

Comment: @erkysun Believe me, “code pages” were hardly the norm 20 years ago. That’s just stupid Microsoft mischief.  People on real computers had their own approaches to these matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unicode string `u"\u4E0D\u65E0"` consists of the two *text* characters `不` and `无`.

When a unicode string is encoded, it is converted into a sequence of *bytes* (not binary). Depending on what encoding is used, there may not be a one-to-one mapping of text characters to bytes. The "utf8" encoding, for instance, can use from one to three bytes to represent a single character:

```
>>> u'\u65E0'.encode('utf8')
'\xe6\x97\xa0'
```

Now, before a sequence of bytes can be *printed*, python (or IDLE) has to try to decode it. But since it has no way to know what encoding was used, it is forced to guess. For some reason, it appears that IDLE may have wrongly guessed "cp1252" for one of the examples:

```
>>> text = u'\u65E0'.encode('utf8').decode('cp1252')
>>> text
u'\xe6\u2014\xa0'
>>> print text
æ—
```

Note that there are *three* characters in `text` - the last one is a non-breaking space.

**EDIT**

Strictly speaking, IDLE wrongly guesses "cp1252" for all three examples. The second one only "succeeds" because each byte coincidently maps to a valid text character ("cp1252" is an 8-bit, single-byte encoding). The other two examples contain the byte `\x8d`, which is not defined in "cp1252". For these cases, IDLE (eventually) falls back to "utf8", which gives the correct output.

Comment: @eryksun. Thanks. I've updated my answer to include your further clarification.

Comment: No, UTF‑8 uses one to **four** bytes to represent a Unicode code point; please edit.  Math letters:       Emoji Warnings:       Gothic:      Alchemical symbols:           Many CJK ideograms:         — etc etc etc

Comment: `python -c 'print(len(chr(0x1F4A9)))'` == 1.  `env PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python -c 'print(chr(0x1F4A9))' | wc -c` == 5, four bytes plus a newline. You will find code point 0x1F4A9 to be an especially excellent one for this sort of testing.

Comment: @tchrist. It is of course true that utf-8 can use four-bytes for representing characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane. But not all versions/builds of python support non-BMP characters, so three-byte utf8 is effectively the limit for a lot of users.

Comment: @ekhumoro Either you assume Unicode, or you get a new language. There is absolutely no excuse not to support full Uniocde.  Accept no substitutes.

Comment: @erkysun Yeah, so? That doesn’t matter.  It’s called Unicode. There is one code: either you support Unicode or you don’t. Anything that doesn’t support full Unicode today is pure trash, and there is no end of superior solutions that are completely free of that sort of crippleware. Wake up! It’s not 1991 anymore.  Geeze!