# How to iterate through all XML Elements and apply logic to each Element's value with ElementTree for Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, celementtree

I am currently trying to apply logic to Element values in a XML file. Specifically I am trying to encode all the values to UTF-8 while not touching any of the element names/attributes themselves.

Here is the sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sd_1>
    <sd_2>
        <sd_3>\311 is a fancy kind of E</sd_3>
    </sd_2>
</sd_1>
```

Currently I have tried 3 methods to achieve this with no success:

First I tried the looping through each element retrieving the values with .text and using .parse:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

et = ET.parse('xml/test.xml')

for child in et.getroot():
    for core in child:
        core_value = str(core.text)
        core.text = core_value.encode('utf-8')

et.write('output.xml')
```

This results in an XML file that does not have the text \311 altered correctly, it just stays as it is.

Next I tried the .iterparse with cElementTree to no avail:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

xml_file_path = 'xml/test.xml'
with open(xml_file_path) as xml_file:
    tree = etree.iterparse(xml_file) 
    for items in tree:
        for item in items:
            print item.text

etree.write('output1.xml')
```

This results in:

```
 "...print item.text\n', "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'..."
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong there, I have seen multiple examples with the same arrangement, but when I print through the elements without the .text I see the tuple with a string value of 'end' at the start and I think that is causing the issue with this method.

How do I properly iterate through my elements, and without specifying the element names e.g. .findall(), apply logic to the values housed in each Element so that when I write the xml to file it saves the changes made when the program was iterating through element values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

et = ET.parse('xml/test.xml')

for child in et.getroot():
    for core in child:
        core_value = str(core.text)
        core.text = core_value.decode('unicode-escape')

et.write('output.xml')
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this existed!  Very helpful!  What is the 'right' thing to do on stackoverflow with my clearly inferior answer?

Comment: @Square, if the characters are actually encoded correctly in the initial document, don't you just need to open it so that they will be displayed as the unicode characters?

Comment: I apologize this is indeed what I was looking for. This is an unfamiliar topic with me and when I loaded it into PlanetPress it came out correctly. Thank you for the prompt and correct answer gauden, and thank you for the help as well alex.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question.  Let's focus on the first method you proposed, as that should be a totally fine way to approach this problem.  When I print out the lines one by one, here is what I get:

```
>>> core_value
'\\311 is a fancy kind of E'
```

What happened for me is that the character was read as a literal '\', which must be escaped to be printed as such.  If we change the escaped character (`\\`) to a non-escaped character (`\`), we get the following:

```
>>> cv = core_value.replace('\\311','\311')
'\xc9 is a fancy kind of E'
>>> print cv
É is a fancy kind of E
```

The weird piece here is that you don't know when in the original file `\311` is "supposed to be" one character or four.  If you know for a fact that those will all be one character, you can write some vile code based on this answer:

[Python Unicode, have unicode number in normal string, want to print unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021331/python-unicode-have-unicode-number-in-normal-string-want-to-print-unicode)

To transorm all of the things that come after a `\` into the correct unicode characters and delete the `\`.